# Is there such thing as an Ubuntu Certification Program, which guarantees compatability?

Tags: hardware-certification

Is there a list or repository which I can refer to so I can see the options of laptop brands or models which are safe to buy?

Comment: With a laptop in particular, I would suggest keeping the windows hard drive intact and installing a new drive.  If you look at the samsung case you'll have warranty difficulties if anything breaks using anyway, so after testing everything under windows you can swap out the drive (also you can get something that suits you better e.g. SSD).  That's what I did on my Acer netbook (maxing out the RAM at the same time).  The only issues I had (which are common on laptops and can be solved with patience) are the laptop-specific function keys (such as internal/external monitor, touchpad on/off).

Answer (score 25):

[Ubuntu has a list of devices that are certified compatible](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop)

One day, when I can afford it, I'll buy a [system76 laptop](https://system76.com/).

Be cautious when considering a Samsung. (see here: [Linux blamed for Samsung laptop deaths](http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2013/01/31/linux-samsung-deaths/1))

If you plan on also using Windows, it's much easier and safer to install Ubuntu *along-side* Windows 7. Some people have experienced issues installing dual-boot along with Windows 8.

ASUS, HP, and Dell have released models with an Ubuntu OS option:

- [HP 255 Notebook PC](http://www.hp.com/hpinfo/newsroom/press_kits/2013/SpringSMBNews/HP255notebook_datasheet.pdf)
- [Asus Eee PC 1225C](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1225C/)
- [Dell XPS 13 Laptop, Developer Edition](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd?~srd=true&sk=Ubuntu&scat=prod)

I believe Dell has Ubuntu pre-installed on other models as an option but there is no option to opt-out of windows unless you buy the XPS. [Dell linux laptops.](http://search.dell.com/results.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=biz&cat=prod&cs=555&k=linux&rpp=20&p=1&subcat=sys%2Fnotebooks&rf=all&nk=f&ira=False&~srd=False&ipsys=False&advsrch=False)

Comment: You should probably move the link to ubuntu.com/certification to the top of the post, as it is the exact answer to the question :)

Comment: Samsungs are okay as long as you install recent versions of Ubuntu (13.10+). I am running 14.04 on a Samsung Series 9 perfectly fine.

Comment: I will say that samsung is known for replacing laptops with Ubuntu installed when allot of other manufacturers would just try to say that using linux voids the warranty http://askubuntu.com/questions/510456/boot-repair-or-ubuntu-grub-somehow-stopped-bios-setup

Answer (score 3):

In my experience Acer laptops run it pretty well, though there is a list of compatible computers that run perfectly with it on [Ubuntu Certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) webpage.

[system76](https://system76.com/) has it installed by default, but have varying tech support success and helpfulness.

Overall, if you have some time you can run it on pretty much anything.

Answer (score 3):

According to Canonical:

**Canonical works closely with Lenovo to certify Ubuntu on a range of their hardware.**

A lot of developers see value in Lenovo Thinkpads for four main reasons:

- Trackpoint Functionality.
- Business Aesthetic.
- Road Warrior (Durable, good battery life).
- Comfortable keyboard.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Lenovo/?page=1

Comment: I work with Lenovo machines everyday. I can absolutely recommend them for Ubuntu - they work very well with no need for any proprietary drivers (other than NVidia for such equipped GPU's). The Haswell-based machines in particular (X240, T440, W540, etc).

Comment: Every time I visit their site; I make sure to bug them about making an "Install with Ubuntu" Default option.