# Boot-repair (Or ubuntu grub) somehow stopped bios setup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, grub2, bios

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 since it launched. All of functioning of bios and grub where running properly. One day I used boot-repair for some reason. After few days I noticed that Bios set-up doesn’t start on hitting F2 (Samsung NP300E5X-S01IN).

I didn't get the reason so I contacted service centre. Due to some other problems, they changed my motherboard. Hard-disk had windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04 installed before. With new motherboard, the grub got disappeared , windows 8 was starting directly and bios set-up started opening on F2, I thought problem is solved.

So, for getting grub to boot ubuntu , I live booted pendrive , installed boot-repair and ran recommended option. Grub installed. It now give option for both OS, but again not bios set-up doesn't open on F2. Tried many times. On hitting F2, it gets directed to Bios.

Can anyone help me in understanding problem ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: what computer is it? and does it have secureboot enabled? if it does then that is the reason boot repair made the system lock down, as it does not recognise what is in the efi partition so it thinks it is a rootkit or someone trying to sideload something to try and get information from the disk without permission

Comment: Hello, Its a Samsung laptop. And yes it may have secure boot enabled in BIOS . But how do it check or disable it ? I mean BIOS setup doesn't starts on F2. I also tried starting firmware setting from windows , ChangePC setting->General->Advanced(Restart)->Troubleshoot->Advanced option . Here also "UEFI Firmware setting". So I am not able to start BIOS setup anyhow.

Comment: really not sure what to tell you. can you go to samsung and ask them to unlock it? once you do that you can turn off secureboot before trying to install ubuntu again

Comment: Ya I called samsung for the same, on hearing the word "Linux" they backed off saying that we don't provide support in anything with includes Linux. So no support for there. Well , thanks for your time, I will try more and wait for some more answers.

Comment: you can say that your device has been bricked by conventional methods in a way that would not be expected so they are obligated to supply support of some sort in repair, elsewise they are voiding their end of the warranty as it was what you could call a hardware fault that was the root cause of the issue.